# Adding values on every clicked image

Tags: android, imageview

I have this code that when I click on one of the images it will set the value to 1. Then if I click on the same image again it will decrease the value to 0. Besides that, when I click on two images, the value would be 2 representing each of the images.

I've tried posting this question once but still the answer is not like what I want. I've also tried making the variable x and z as a global variable but its not working. So can you help me. Thank you

```
public void onClick(View v)
    { 
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.oneImgView:
            images[0].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            images[1].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(images[0].getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                setValue(1);
            }
            display();
            break;
        case R.id.twoImgView:
            images[1].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            images[0].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(images[1].getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                setValue(-1);
            }
            display();
            break;
        case R.id.threeImgView:
            images[2].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if(images[2].getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                setValue(1);
            }
            images[3].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            display();
            break;
        case R.id.fourImgView:
            images[3].setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if(images[3].getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                setValue(-1);
            }
            images[2].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            display();
            break;
        }
    }

    public void display()
    {
        z =+ getValue();

        //if(z==1){
            //display.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);}
            tView.setText(""+z);//}
        }


    public int getValue() {
        int x=+value;
        return x;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more ? What should happen ? Like whats the problem

Comment: @AdnanMulla the problem is that the value do not increase when i click on two images or more. The value is still 1. How can I make the value become 2 or increasing as the image is being clicked?

Answer (score 0):

That should be simple using 4 boolean variables. I have set all the 4 variables to true at beginning and then based on whether they are clicked 1st time or the 2nd i add or subtract the value.

```
  boolean img1=false;
  boolean img2=false;
  boolean img3=false;
  boolean img4=false;

  public void onClick(View v)
{ 
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.oneImgView:
    if(img1){
       z =z+1;
       img1 = false;
    }else{
       z = z-1;
       img1 = true;
    }
    case R.id.twoImgView : 
    if(img2){
       z =z+1;
       img2 = false;
    }else{
       z = z-1;
       img2 = true;
    }
    case R.id.threeImgView:
    if(img3){
       z =z+1;
       img3 = false;
    }else{
       z = z-1;
       img3 = true;
    }
    case R.id.fourImgView : 
    if(img4){
       z =z+1;
       img4 = false;
    }else{
       z = z-1;
       img4 = true;
    }

   }
```

That should handle the image count for you, add whatever other logic you have !Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code. But i still don't understand how can i display the number just like the function display() in my coding above

Comment: I've already tried your coding and it's not working. I'm not really sure where to put the coding you gave into my coding. Can you help me again sir thank you